# Xamarin Forms - button to scroll to top of ScrollView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin Forms app I have placed a button at the bottom of a ScrollView which the user should be able to click to auto scroll back to the top of the page.

The code I put behind the button is

```
await myScrollView.ScrollToAsync(0, firstImage.Y, true);
```

firstImage being the first item on the page.
However, when clicked the page only scrolls up partially, am I missing something here?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add that in your code behind

```
    public void ScrollUp(Object o)
    {
        List.ScrollTo(o, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
    }
```

When you click the button, sent the first element from your list and call this method

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this to move y-axis.Please note with every click on button you should increase scroll position like below to make it work.Similary you can implement the same on scroll down.I used intial value as 25 as per my requirement in ipad app.You can customize these value as per your needs.

```
   double yaxis = 0;

    private async void ScrolledUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            yaxis = yaxis + 25;
            if (yaxis > 125)
            {
                yaxis = 0;
            }
            await scroll.ScrollToAsync(0, yaxis, false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");

        }
    }
```